# vuejs cannot display image from assets folder

Tags: image, vue.js

I tried to upload an image from my asset but nothing appears. I would like the image source to match the value set in `character.headImage`.

data/character.js

```
export const character = [
  {
    name : 'Super Lady',
    fullImage : '../assets/characters/superLadyFull.png',
    headImage : '../assets/characters/superLadyHead.png',
    description : '少し恥ずかしがり屋の女の子 好きなことは買い物、カフェ巡り'

  }
]
```

charactersSelection.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    select the characther
    <div v-for="character in characters">
        <img :src="character.headImage">
        <p>{{character.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {character} from "../data/Character";

  export default {
    name: "CharactersSelection",
    data() {
        return {
            characters : character
        }
    }
  } 
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This looks like a relative pathing thing, can you get to the images directly from where you're serving them? Eg 'localhost:8080/assets/characters/sukperLadyHead.png"?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you want your image to look like this

```
<img src="assets/characters/superLadyHead.png">
```

Change your character image source strings to reflect the following

```
export const character = [
  {
    name : 'Super Lady',
    fullImage : 'assets/characters/superLadyFull.png',
    headImage : 'assets/characters/superLadyHead.png',
    description : '少し恥ずかしがり屋の女の子 好きなことは買い物、カフェ巡り'

  }
]
```

However, this makes some assumptions about how your page is being served.